# How to extract multiple text on a text file with a scripting language

Tags: python, perl, batch-file, scripting

Most likely this has been asked but I haven't been able to get a good sense of codes out there to achieve what I am after.

I have a text file with 1000 entries like the following 3 consecutive entries. out of that text file I want to extract

**number.xml** and its corresponding **Current video timing: 1280x720p 60Hz**
and spit it on a text file one by one.

```
Report complete.on: E01A040E.xml
EDID raw data:
---  00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F
000  00 FF FF FF FF FF FF 00 4C 2D FC 08 00 00 00 00 
010  29 15 01 03 80 10 09 78 0A EE 91 A3 54 4C 99 26 
020  0F 50 54 BD EE 00 81 C0 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 
030  01 01 01 01 01 01 66 21 56 AA 51 00 1E 30 46 8F 
040  33 00 A0 5A 00 00 00 1E 01 1D 00 72 51 D0 1E 20 
050  6E 28 55 00 A0 5A 00 00 00 1E 00 00 00 FD 00 18 
060  4B 0F 44 17 00 0A 20 20 20 20 20 20 00 00 00 FC 
070  00 53 41 4D 53 55 4E 47 0A 20 20 20 20 20 01 6D 
080  02 03 1F F1 47 84 05 03 10 20 22 07 23 09 07 07 
090  83 01 00 00 E2 00 0F 67 03 0C 00 10 00 B8 2D 01 
0A0  1D 80 18 71 1C 16 20 58 2C 25 00 A0 5A 00 00 00 
0B0  9E 8C 0A D0 8A 20 E0 2D 10 10 3E 96 00 A0 5A 00 
0C0  00 00 18 02 3A 80 18 71 38 2D 40 58 2C 45 00 A0 
0D0  5A 00 00 00 1E 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
0E0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
0F0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 FD 
+5V: OK
Video information:
- Current video timing: 1280x720p 60Hz
- Incoming video matches CEA-861 VIC 4 and 69 exactly
- HDMI video detected
- Received AVI VIC 4
- Color space: YCbCr 4:4:4 8 bpc
# 
EDID description: E01A0A8A.xml
EDID raw data:
---  00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F
000  00 FF FF FF FF FF FF 00 4C 2D FC 08 00 00 00 00 
010  29 15 01 03 80 10 09 78 0A EE 91 A3 54 4C 99 26 
020  0F 50 54 BD EE 00 81 C0 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 
030  01 01 01 01 01 01 66 21 56 AA 51 00 1E 30 46 8F 
040  33 00 A0 5A 00 00 00 1E 01 1D 00 72 51 D0 1E 20 
050  6E 28 55 00 A0 5A 00 00 00 1E 00 00 00 FD 00 18 
060  4B 0F 44 17 00 0A 20 20 20 20 20 20 00 00 00 FC 
070  00 53 41 4D 53 55 4E 47 0A 20 20 20 20 20 01 6D 
080  02 03 1F F1 47 84 05 03 10 20 22 07 23 09 07 07 
090  83 01 00 00 E2 00 0F 67 03 0C 00 10 00 B8 2D 01 
0A0  1D 80 18 71 1C 16 20 58 2C 25 00 A0 5A 00 00 00 
0B0  9E 8C 0A D0 8A 20 E0 2D 10 10 3E 96 00 A0 5A 00 
0C0  00 00 18 02 3A 80 18 71 38 2D 40 58 2C 45 00 A0 
0D0  5A 00 00 00 1E 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
0E0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
0F0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 FD 
+5V: OK
Video information:
- Current video timing: 1280x720p 60Hz
- Incoming video matches CEA-861 VIC 4 and 69 exactly
- HDMI video detected
- Received AVI VIC 4
- Color space: YCbCr 4:4:4 8 bpc
# 
EDID description: E01A0C88.xml
EDID raw data:
---  00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F
000  00 FF FF FF FF FF FF 00 08 59 42 00 01 00 00 00 
010  01 16 01 03 80 45 27 78 0A D0 DD A9 53 49 9D 23 
020  11 47 4A A3 08 00 81 C0 81 00 81 0F 81 40 81 80 
030  95 00 B3 00 01 01 52 35 80 80 70 38 1F 40 20 20 
040  13 00 C4 8E 21 00 00 1E 46 20 00 A4 51 00 2A 30 
050  50 80 37 00 20 46 21 00 00 1A 00 00 00 FC 00 4E 
060  53 2D 33 32 4C 32 34 30 41 31 33 0A 00 00 00 FD 
070  00 37 4C 1E 50 11 00 0A 20 20 20 20 20 20 01 23 
080  02 03 20 73 48 05 04 03 02 01 06 07 90 26 09 07 
090  07 15 07 50 83 01 00 00 67 03 0C 00 10 00 B8 2D 
0A0  01 1D 00 72 51 D0 1E 20 6E 28 55 00 C4 8E 21 00 
0B0  00 1E 8C 0A D0 8A 20 E0 2D 10 10 3E 96 00 13 8E 
0C0  21 00 00 18 01 1D 80 18 71 1C 16 20 58 2C 25 00 
0D0  C4 8E 21 00 00 9E 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
0E0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
0F0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 53 
+5V: OK
Video information:
- Current video timing: 1280x720p 60Hz
- Incoming video matches CEA-861 VIC 4 and 69 exactly
- HDMI video detected
- Received AVI VIC 4
- Color space: YCbCr 4:4:4 8 bpc
```

this is the code I have so far but hasnt worked for me. This is done in python, but if it can be done any other scripting language. Just that I am not to used to doing scripting. Thanks a million to those that give a helping hand.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

inFile = open("batch01.txt")
outFile = open("result.txt", "w")

with open('batch01.txt') as infile, open('result.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    copy = False
    for line in infile:
        if line.strip() == "EDID description:":
            copy = True
        elif line.strip() == "- Current video timing":
            copy = True
        elif copy:
            outfile.write(line)

inFile.close()
outFile.close()
```

Comment: @Community: Why the downvotes on this question? If you downvote it, at least explain your reasons in a comment... :(

Comment: I was thinking the same thing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below there is a Batch-file .bat solution, that I think is simpler...

**EDIT**: *Program modifed as requested in comment*

```
@echo off
(for /F "tokens=3-6" %%a in ('findstr /L ".xml Current" batch01.txt') do (
   if "%%b" equ "" (
      set /P "=%%a - " < NUL
   ) else (
      if "%%c" equ "" (
         echo No VSYNC detected
      ) else (
         echo Current video timing: %%c %%d
      )
   )
)) > result.txt
```

Output:

```
E01A040E.xml - Current video timing: 1280x720p 60Hz
E01A0A8A.xml - Current video timing: 1280x720p 60Hz
E01A0C88.xml - Current video timing: 1280x720p 60Hz
```

Comment: this was exactly what I was looking to do. But didn't know if it would be possible to be done in a batch file. Would you mind explaining why of the "tokens=3,5,6" I am assuming that %%a %%b %%c correspond to the each tokens, is that correct? thank you so much.

Comment: quick question, let say that there is no Current video timing and instead for it to be blank. I would like for it to say No VSYNC detected. I played around with your code but haven't been able to achieve it at this point.

Comment: Exactly. Each letter correspond to the next token defined in `"tokens=...` part. By default, the tokens in the input line are separated by spaces or tabs. See the edit in my answer and compare how I used the tokens now vs. the previous version.

Answer (score 2):

I would use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) to do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import re

with open('batch01.txt') as infile, open('result.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        m = re.search('(EDID description|- Current video timing): (.*)', line)
        if m is not None:
            outfile.write(m.group(2) + '\n')
```

This will print out

```
1280x720p 60Hz
E01A0A8A.xml
1280x720p 60Hz
E01A0C88.xml
1280x720p 60Hz
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you actually need to be checking whether a given line starts with certain substrings, rather than a full exact comparison (which is what the `==` operator gives you).  Instead, your `for` loop should use the `startswith` method to look at the beginning of the line and look closer to this:

```
for line in infile:
    if line.strip().startswith("EDID description:"):
        copy = True
    elif line.strip().startswith("Report complete.on:"):  # Based on your data, it seems like you need to check for these as well - maybe not?
        copy = True
    elif line.strip().startswith("- Current video timing"):
        copy = True
    else:
        copy = False
    if copy:
        outfile.write(line)
```

But the loop can be streamlined significantly:

```
prefixes = [
 "EDID description:", "Report complete.on:", "- Current video timing"
]
for line in infile:
    for prefix in prefixes:
        if line.strip().startswith(prefix):
            outfile.write(line)
            break
```

This eliminates the multi-branched `if`/`elif` structure as well as the boolean `copy` flag.

With your sample input data, I got this in the result file:

```
Report complete.on: E01A040E.xml
- Current video timing: 1280x720p 60Hz
EDID description: E01A0A8A.xml
- Current video timing: 1280x720p 60Hz
EDID description: E01A0C88.xml
- Current video timing: 1280x720p 60Hz
```

Again, I'm not sure whether you wanted that "Report complete.on" line or not, but it looked to me like you do.

Answer (score 1):

Without actually running this I see three issues that you need to resolve.

1. Your equality conditions in the if/elif control structure will never be true.
2. Assume for a moment that what I described in number 1 is true; the final elif will not actually be reached because once either of the preceeding expressions evaluates as true, the rest of the if/elif short-circuits and doesn't check for additional conditions.
3. You need to "reset" copy = False before the next iteration of your for loop otherwise copy will remain true for everything after the first time copy = True is set.

Suggested fixes:

1. Use something like 'line.strip().find('EDID description:')' to determine if the line **contains** the string you are looking for.  Again,  you need to determine if the substring is **in** the line, **not equal to the line.**
2. You need to move your copy operation outside of the if/elif structure.  That is, instead of making it part of the same if/elif structure, create a separate 'if copy:' structure after the current one to output the line if the line was found.
3. After you output the line, set copy=False so that the next iteration of the for loop is initialized properly.  Otherwise you'll have every line after the first match print.

Something like this:  (I have not actually tested this...)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

inFile = open("batch01.txt")
outFile = open("result.txt", "w")

with open('batch01.txt') as infile, open('result.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    copy = False
    for line in infile:
        # use the find to see if the line CONTAINS the string you are looking for
        if line.strip().find("EDID description:"):
            copy = True
        elif line.strip().find("- Current video timing"):
            copy = True

        # make this a separate if
        if copy:
            outfile.write(line)

        # reset this to False to it can be evaluated and set properly in the next iteration
        copy = False

inFile.close()
outFile.close()
```

Hope this helps.